Microsoft Office 2016 and OAuth2
The matter is discussed at length on various help websites but the answers are either too old or not fitting what I need.
I have MS Outlook Professionnel Plus 2016 (16.0.5456.1000) MSO, and an ordinary Hotmail email address with IMAP protocol (on Win 10 2H22 19045.4651). Microsoft just sent an email as to how the connection is not secure enough and come September I won't be able to access my email that way.
Edit: Roughly translated (it's in French), it states that come Sept. 16th, apps that use a less secure connection won't be able to access my mailbox. "Update your sign-in technology before September 16th, 2024 to maintain email access'."
There seem to be a lot of solutions for Exchange Online and 365, but none seem to work for ordinary at-home setups.
Question is: is there, at this time, a way to set up OAuth2 with Office 2016 (and how)? If not, is there a more recent version of Office Outlook (not 365) that would allow such a thing (it doesn't seem to work for 2021)?
Adding EnableADAL=1 word in the registry HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity doesn't work (it seems to be exclusive to 365 clients).

Can you provide us the text of exactly what you received. Helps to understand if this is a Hotmail issue or an Outlook issue

Just added the object of the email. It is a Hotmail issue as far as I'm concerned as a friend using Thunderbird (she forced "normal password" to be able to input it every time she opened the TB app) received the same email.

What OS are you running Office 2016 on? If Windows, can you switch to the Windows Mail/(New) Outlook app instead of O2016?

As stated in the post, I'm on Win 10 2H22. I want to use Office Outlook and not (new) Outlook as I work with .pst files (and that app is frankly not that great to use).

As i know, if you are using Outlook.com account:
Outlook supports Modern Authentication in all current Microsoft 365 subscription SKUs and Outlook 2021 LTSC (any SKU with build 11601.10000 or higher) when connecting directly as Outlook.com.
The following versions of Outlook Desktop do not support Modern Authentication for Outlook.com:  Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010, Outlook 2013, Outlook 2016 MSI, Outlook 2019 LTSC. Any release of Outlook Desktop with a version less than 11601.10000 does not support Modern Authentication for Outlook.com.
More information: Modern Authentication Methods now needed to continue syncing Outlook Email in non-Microsoft email apps
If you are using an Exchange online account, Office 2016 is supported.
More information: How modern authentication works for Office 2016 and Office 2019 client apps.

I read that too but I had a hard time figuring out whether I have Exchange online (turns out it's used for businesses, not personal accounts; there used to be an Exchange ActiveSync that doesn't work with 2016 anymore, hence the switch to IMAP). I also read forums where people had 2021 versions that didn't work with Modern Auth. (despite confirmation by MS people). It's just that there are a 1000 things called "Outlook" and it's getting hard to tell them apart when people try to explain how things work.
